# Moving site from WordPress to Drupal

Tags: wordpress, drupal, installation

I've been moving a CiviCRM from WordPress to Drupal but getting a strange array of errors.

It's on the same hosting so I've set up a new database for the new CiviCRM, moved all the tables except the 4 cache tables and the domain. I've cleared all the cache, rebuild menus, (attempted) to sync the users (only got about 180 out of 280 but that's a good start).

My problem is that a number of the pages in CiviCRM throw up the 'DB table does not exist' error:
When I edit/create a contact
Organisation address and contact info
The page to edit the navigation menu opens but the triangle is just spinning
Quick search doesn't work (nothing happens) but Find Contacts does work.

I've turned on the advanced logging, and getting errors like the following:

```
Notice: Undefined index: frontend_title in CRM_UF_Page_Group->browse() (line 329 of /home/xxx/www/data/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/UF/Page/Group.php).
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Rose, for the 'DB table does not exist' messages - which tables is it complaining about?  Do those tables actually exist in the db?

Comment: Yes - checked all tables and they're exactly the same as the WordPress site. Actually - thinking out loud - it was also having similar problems at one point because I'd updated the files to 5.2.2 and run the update script and then rolled back to a back-up. Once I'd re-run the update script, it was fine. The update script didn't work for the new site (it was installed as 5.2.2 so just said there was no need to run the script) but I might re-do the installation (they were on different versions when I first installed it - that may have caused the issue?)

Comment: So, these were the steps I just took:

Comment: So, these were the steps I just took:
* delete the database
* delete the civicrm.settings.php file
* Re-run the install page for CiviCRM
* Restore from last night's back-up all tables except the 4 cache tables, domain and uf_match

Also, to clarify (my mistake), the error message says "DB error: no such field"

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the back up hadn't recorded the updated version of CiviCRM (it may have happened before I reran the update script) so when I checked the domain table in the back-up just now, it was still showing version 4.7.29. I did a manual back-up AFTER double-checking the domain/version was correct in the WordPress site, then I copied over the database tables again and it's working.